# How to create a parent-child dataframe from an existing pandas dataframe of hierarchical structure and arbitrary shape?

Tags: python, pandas, hierarchical-data

How do you convert a given dataframe with a hierarchical structure and arbitrary shape (say, similar to the one below) into a new dataframe with a parent and child column?

Edit: Note that a constraint is that a child cannot be its own parent.

```
data = {'level1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
        'level2': ['James', 'Robert', 'Patricia', 'Patricia', 'John'],
        'level3': ['Stockholm', 'Denver', 'Moscow', 'Moscow', 'Palermo'],
        'level4': ['red', 'Denver', 'yellow', 'purple', 'blue']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

  level1    level2     level3  level4
0      A     James  Stockholm     red
1      A    Robert     Denver  Denver
2      B  Patricia     Moscow  yellow
3      B  Patricia     Moscow  purple
4      C      John    Palermo    blue
```

Desired output is something like this:

```
       parent      child
0           A      James
1           A     Robert
2           B   Patricia
3           C       John
4       James  Stockholm
5      Robert     Denver
6    Patricia     Moscow
7        John    Palermo
8   Stockholm        red
9      Moscow     yellow
10     Moscow     purple
11    Palermo       blue
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem here? It would be best if you could provide the desired output too. It might help us to provide you with better answers.

Comment: @AmirhosseinKiani, yes, of course. I added the desired output on your suggestion.

Comment: The dataframe you have shown with the name `df` differs from the one used in the `data` variable. Please keep that in mind when you look at my answer and output.

Comment: @AmirhosseinKiani Yes, you're right. Revised. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I can think of is using a for loop over the columns of the dataframe:

```py
columns = df.columns
length = len(columns)
parent = []
children = []
for i in range(length):
  if i != length - 1 :
    parent += df[columns[i]].to_list()
    children += df[columns[i+1]].to_list()
newDf = pd.DataFrame({"parent":parent, "children":children}).drop_duplicates()
newDf[newDf["parent"] != newDf["children"]]
```

##### Output

```
       parent   children
0           A      James
1           A     Robert
2           B   Patricia
4           C       John
5       James  Stockholm
6      Robert     Denver
7    Patricia     Moscow
9        John    Palermo
10  Stockholm        red
12     Moscow     yellow
13     Moscow     purple
14    Palermo       blue
```

Comment: Row 11 in your output would be undesirable because a child can't be its own parent. What would be a way such that we exclude that type of row from the output?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @user2962397 . I have edited the answer as per your comment.